# Connecting Vagrant to Consul server in OpenStack

Tags: vagrant, openstack

How can I connect a Vagrant machine to a Consul server running in an OpenStack cluster?

I have 2 instances in an OpenStack cluster. One is running as a Consul server (agent-one) and the other just as a client (agent-two). They are joined and reporting passing health checks.

On my local machine I spun up a Vagrant (vagrant-one) on my local machine and wanted to join the Consul party in OpenStack.

At this point the consul log on vagrant-one reads:

```
2014/09/26 18:02:42 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: vagrant-one 10.0.2.15
2014/09/26 18:02:42 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
```

I ran `consul join <consul-server-hostname>` and it reported:

```
Successfully joined cluster by contacting 1 nodes.
```

The log then reported the following sequence of events on vagrant-one:

```
2014/09/26 18:07:22 [INFO] agent.rpc: Accepted client: 127.0.0.1:39070
2014/09/26 18:07:22 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joining: [consul-server-hostname]
2014/09/26 18:07:27 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: agent-two 10.4.128.18
2014/09/26 18:07:27 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: agent-one 10.4.128.17
2014/09/26 18:07:27 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joined: 1 Err: <nil>
2014/09/26 18:07:27 [INFO] consul: adding server agent-one (Addr: 10.4.128.17:8300) (DC: dc1)
2014/09/26 18:07:29 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-one has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:30 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-two has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:31 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-one has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:32 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-two has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:33 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-two has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:34 [INFO] memberlist: Marking agent-one as failed, suspect timeout reached
2014/09/26 18:07:34 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: agent-one 10.4.128.17
2014/09/26 18:07:34 [INFO] consul: removing server agent-one (Addr: 10.4.128.17:8300) (DC: dc1)
2014/09/26 18:07:34 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-one has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:35 [INFO] memberlist: Marking agent-two as failed, suspect timeout reached
2014/09/26 18:07:35 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: agent-two 10.4.128.18
2014/09/26 18:07:35 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect agent-two has failed, no acks received
2014/09/26 18:07:37 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: rpc error: failed to get conn: dial tcp 10.4.128.17:8300: i/o timeout
2014/09/26 18:07:47 [INFO] serf: attempting reconnect to agent-one 10.4.128.17:8301
2014/09/26 18:07:57 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
```

So it looks like it is able to connect initially. It get's the node names of the two consul agents running in the OpenStack cluster. None of the health checks on the nodes in the OpenStack cluster ever pass and vagrant-one eventually reverts back to "No known Consul servers".

### Edit 1

If I add a `-advertise <associated-ip>` flag to the OpenStack Consul agents then vagrant-one seems to be able to receive the health checks of agent-two but not agent-one for some reason. It seems though at this point that this problem is a networking issue.

Comment: I cannot figure what the question is, @ogc-nick.

Answer (score 0):

Your Vagrant box runs on the Virtual NAT of your Virtualbox (or VMWare). The Nodes in the Openstack Cluster are exposed to the LAN but the Vagrant box is not. The simplest fix is to expose your Vagrant box to the external network. Add the following to your Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```